# Whiteline issues while popping from view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

My case navigation bar color different for two controllers. When I pop from a second view controller to first one there is white line glitch in UI appears. I don't understand why issues happen, is set navigation bar shadow image to nil and use a background image for setting navigation bar background.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

one reason that can cause this, is extra content from other screens overlapping each other..

try to set each view controller to have

```
clipsToBounds = true
```

See Description from Apple...

> Setting this value to true causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds
>   of the receiver. If set to false, subviews whose frames extend beyond
>   the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default value
>   is false.

another cause is, some view controller has a background with clear color...
make sure each view controller has a non clear background.

**EDIT**

the question was not clear enough, it looks like I didn't understand well, try to change the tint color of navigation bar to clear.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found my issues, issues are when I am setting a navigation bar from orange to white I set the translucent property of the navigation bar is true. which cause the problem for me to display a white line.